# Default value in WPF Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, default-value

I've bound the `Height` and `Width` of my window. Now, the window is so tiny in Visual Studio I can't work on it anymore. Setting default values to `Height` and `Width` would solve my problem. Is it possible in `Binding`?

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="Sth.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Width="{Binding Path=WidthOfImage, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Height="{Binding Path=HeightOfImage, Mode=TwoWay}"
    >
    ...
</Window>
```

Can we set default values in WPF `Binding`? How?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See [`FallbackValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="Sth.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Width="{Binding Path=WidthOfImage, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=200}"
    Height="{Binding Path=HeightOfImage, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=150}"
    >
    ...
</Window>
```

You might also be able to use [`MinWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minwidth.aspx) or [`MinHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minheight.aspx) to address your small window issue.