# WPF OneWayToSource binding initial value

Tags: wpf, binding, default-value, oneway

I have a `RadioButton` element whose `IsChecked` property is bound to `MyProperty` in `ViewModel`. The `Binding` has mode `OneWayToSource` for some reasons, it pushes the value from `RadioButton.IsChecked` to `ViewModel.MyProperty`.

`RadioButton.IsChecked` is initially `false`, now. I want to set an initial value from `ViewModel`, which might be even `true`. I cannot do that because the property is occupied by the binding.

Is there any way to use `Binding` with that mode and set default value to the bound property in UI? Something like that:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource, DefaultVaule=???}">
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default values in WPF DataBinding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238905/default-values-in-wpf-databinding)

Comment: so do you mean that you want to push the value from control's property to the view model and you are not able to set the value because the property is occupied by binding and there is no other option available in binding? if yes then perhaps defaulting the FallbackValue in binding and the default value of the view model property to same value may help you achieve the same. by default the default value for `boolean` and `IsChecked` is `false` so you may not require any change unless you want default to be true.

Comment: In first sentence you described exactly what I mean. And I want set `IsChecked` as `True` - that is the problem.

Comment: @pushpraj conceptually, `FallbackValue` is not quite fit for my situation, but it is working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood you correct, I think this might help:

You can define the default value through the [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) property. You can define a [FallbackValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) value in case of error either, for example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, TargetNullValue=0, FallbackValue=10}" />
```

see here:
[enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7bb485a8-be7a-470d-a8e7-c133b8bab8dc/databinding-default-value?forum=wpf)

Comment: No, this will not work, I've already seen that post.  `TargetNullValue` is used when property of target equals `Null`. But I have `Boolean` property.